# What is the suitable ML algorithm for compare the accelerometer sensor data?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

I'm a newbie to the machine learning. I want to use machine learning for compare the data I have collected from mobile phone accelerometer sensor. I have the data comma separated with the longitude and latitude.

Let's assume that I have got data from riding a car in street x as values 1( below). If I'm having multiple data for the same street by driving the same vehicle, I want to train a model from that data. So, the model will be trained using accelerometer sensor data, longitude, latitude and vehicle type. After that I want to identify the vehicle type if there is a new data without vehicle type.

Could I have a suggestion for the appropriate machine learning algorithm for this scenario?

values 1: 
[0.41 80.21464327 6.03746252, -0.22 80.21464182 6.03751725, -0.47 80.21464501 6.03756485, -0.17 80.21464358 6.03760711, -0.59 80.2146479 6.03764445, -1.07 80.21465786 6.03767261, 0.24 80.21466478 6.0377051, -0.7 80.21466468 6.03774136, 0.68 80.21466873 6.0377806, 1.03 80.21467383 6.03782412, -0.3 80.21467654 6.03786671, 0.39 80.21467859 6.03791466, 0.21 80.21468187 6.03795632, 0.06 80.21468436 6.03800212, 0.22 80.21468421 6.03804084, 0.62 80.21469052 6.03807511]

Comment: So let me understand. Your data is streets with set of values representing these streets. You want to know if given set of values is representing one of the streets you have and if it does - which one.

Comment: If the answer to both of my questions is yes, than you don't need ML and you can simple think of some distance function between these vectors.

Comment: @Yonlif, I think the way I have address the problem is incorrect. Sorry for that I have  edited the question. Could you help me?

Comment: What is your hypothesis for how the accelerometer data for two different vehicles will be the same? That the bumpers act differently? That the breaking and going up to speed is different rate (also influenced a lot by driver)?

Comment: @jonnor, I have make assumptions that vehicles are driven at a same speed.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem of vehicle detection sounds like it might be quite difficult, as the variation between your classes (different vehicles) is possibly very small compared to the other sources of variation in your data (different drivers, different traffic situation, differences in sensors).

So to start, I would capture some data collected under very controlled circumstances:
Have two different cars follow eachother as closely as possible on some stretches of road. Do multiple runs on the same stretch of road, trying to make conditions as similar as possible. Switch drivers, and repeat the collection. Switch phones and repeat collection.

The first you need to make sure is that your accelerometer vectors are always referring to the same direction. Online estimation of the gravity vector and then transforming the coordinate space accordingly is the standard approach.

Secondly you need to transform the data into a meaningful set of features. I recommend computing the Short-Time-Fourier-Transform to get spectrograms. Then you can do some Exploratory Data Analysis to try to see if there actually is a difference between vehicles and what nature it has. Once you have an understanding of that, then you can think about designing a model.

The most well-documented accelerometer problems similar to this one is Human Activity Detection, you should check the literature for more details.